# Arduino command parsing

Tags: arduino, int, udp

I am writing an ESP32 project which receives an UDP packet and based on it some action should be carried out. There are those commands:

```
FON
FOFF
MSC <INT> <INT>
TC <INT>
```

I receive the message like this:

```
void receiveUdpMessages(){
  int udpMsgLength = Udp.parsePacket(); 
  if(udpMsgLength != 0){
      byte udpPacket[udpMsgLength+1];
      IPAddress senderIp = Udp.remoteIP();
      Udp.read(udpPacket, udpMsgLength);
      udpPacket[udpMsgLength] = 0;
      Udp.flush(); 

      Serial.println("Received UDP Message from : " + String(senderIp[0]) + "." + String(senderIp[1]) + "." + String(senderIp[2])+ "."+ String(senderIp[3]));

      processReceivedMessage((char *)udpPacket);
  }
}
```

and this is the processReceivedMessage method:

```
void processReceivedMessage(char *message){
    if(strncmp("FON",message,3)==0){
      setParameters(ct, 100);  
    }else if(strncmp("FOFF",message,4)==0){
      setParameters(ct, 0);  
    }else if(strncmp("MSC",message,3)==0){

    }else if(strncmp("TC",message,2)==0){

    }
}
```

My question is what is the best way to split both of the ints for the parameterized commands? Also if you notice any sort of issue with above code please tell me I did not have an opportunity to test it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's actually two seperate steps here:

1. Find where the integers substrings start in your message
2. Convert those substrings to actual `int`s

For step 1, there are many ways to do this, but using `strchr` is probably the easiest for your purposes.

For step 2, either use `atoi` or the safer-but-harder-to-use `strtol`

Here's an example for the `MSC` message, the one for processing the `TC` message will be very similar.

I've kept it as one function for clarity, but there's scope for refactoring it.

```
void process_msc_message(char * message)
{
    int integers[2];
    // strchr returns a pointer to the space character
    char* substring = strchr(message, ' ');
    if (substring)
    {
        // atoi will convert the first number it finds in the given string
        integers[0] = atoi(substring); 
    }

    // Jump forward to the next number
    substring = strchr(substring+1, ' ');
    if (substring)
    {
        integers[1] = atoi(substring);
    }

    // Do something with the integers...

}
```

Comment: Wow I did not know that there was function returning pointer to next space. That will come in handy for sure. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

You can give it any character to search for. It will returns NULL if that character isn't in the string.